# How to remove rows with cells of value zero given a condition?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

Consider a dataframe with the first column consisting of protein names and then subsequent columns being: day1_trial1, day1_trial2, day1_trial3, day2_trial1, day2_trial2, day2_trial3.

If I wanted to remove rows from the dataframe that have at least 2 zero values for one or more of the days (i.e. I want to remove rows where 2 or more values for the three trials of any day are zero), how could I accomplish this?

So far, the stackoverflow posts on removing rows in pandas based on conditions don't seem to be able to differentiate between different groups of columns. I was wondering if there was a way I could be able to do that?

Comment: You should likely use a MultiIndex with one level for the day and one for the trial number, this will make things much easier. Please provide a minimal reproducible example of your data.

Comment: @mozway I was actually thinking that I might create two dataframes: one with the day 1 trials and one with the day 2 trials. I will then apply the condition that if there are 2 or more cells with value of zero in a row, that row will be dropped, to each of the two new dataframes. Then I will find the intersection of the remaining rows (i.e. the intersection of the remaining proteins) left in the two new dataframes. Do you know how I can then keep just these rows in my original dataframe? Is there some way to loop through each row and see if it is in the list of proteins to keep?

Answer (score 0):

Like @Mozway mentioned, I would go for the MultiIndex solution, the `groupby(level=0, axis=1)` groups the columns based on the first level of the MultiIndex, which represents the day. Then, `apply(lambda x: x.eq(0).sum(axis=1))` is used to count the number of zero values for each group (day).

```py
import pandas as pd

# Assuming your dataframe is named 'df'

zero_counts = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.eq(0).sum(axis=1))

filtered_df = df[zero_counts.lt(2).all(axis=1)]

print(filtered_df)
```

The `zero_counts` dataframe will have the same MultiIndex structure as the original dataframe, but with the count of zeros for each day. By using `lt(2).all(axis=1)`, we create a boolean mask that checks if all the trials for each day have fewer than 2 zero values.